# Поломался сайт

Tags: html, css

Мои знания на уровне ХТМЛ для чайников, в ЦСС только начинаю разбиратся, в этой связи случилось следующее. Чего-то поставил, последовательность не помню :(
Может форум, может изменял чего-то в страницах [сайта](http://69vip.ucoz.ru), может ещё первый контейнер.
Вот ссылка на сайт короче. Проблема заключается в том, что съехал левый (первый) контенер под содержание страницы! Как вылечить?

Comment: Очень важно!...проблема наблюдается только на главной странице. На остальных ничего похожего нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой-то ужас в dom'е. половина того, что должно быть в head попала в body.
Конкретно по ошибке:
`<div class="side_block">` попал внутрь `<div class="conten">`, а должен быть на одном уровне, т.е. следовать за ним (так по крайней мере на странице с новостями).

Но вообще по хорошему надо шаблон приводить в порядок, сейчас там каша.

Answer (score 0):

Воообщем у тебя

```
<div class="side_block">
```

внутри

```
<div class="conten">
```

а должен быть внутри

```
<div class="cont">
```

подними `<div class="side_block">` на один уровень вложенности, инфа 100% :O

p.s. Ищи не закрытый тег в коде, инфа 100%

p.s. s. Как закроешь не закрыйтый тег, все должно встать нормально, не нужно будет ничего менять в верстке.